# includedByState & includes filter not working with ngClass

Tags: angular, css, state

I created a sample application using angular 7 material. For navigation to highlight the selected one i used active class. when i used 5 li elements to highlight the selected one used `$state` filter dynamically using `ngClass` with state filter `includedByState` and `$state.includes` separately , but it doesn't work.

I need a UI like this

[sample application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1sD.png)

```css
CSS

.navigation-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  min-width: 10%;
}

li.active::after {
  content: " ";
  opacity: 1;
  top: 12%;
  left: 8%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ccd7de;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="navigation-items nav nav-tabs">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{ active: ('home' | includedByState) }">
      <a [routerLink]="['/home']" data-toggle="tab" ui-sref="home" title="Home">
        <mat-icon class="one">home</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: $state.includes('myapp') }">
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/myapp']"
        data-toggle="tab"
        ui-sref="myapp"
        title="My Application"
      >
        <mat-icon class="two">assignment</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{active: $state.includes('myContact') }">
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/myContact']"
        data-toggle="tab"
        ui-sref="myContact"
        title="My Contact"
      >
        <mat-icon class="three">folder_open</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two router implementations there. One is [Angular](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) router and the second is [UI Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/).

- `ui-sref="myapp"` is UI Router directive
- `[routerLink]="['/myapp']"` is Angular router directive

You have both of them on the same element.

With UI Router you add class when state is active just with `ui-sref-active="active"`. But you already have it there and it is not working, so i assume that you don't really have UI router in your dependencies. [(see the tutorial)](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/tutorial/helloworld)

With Angular router you add class to element when state is active with `routerLinkActive` [(see doc)](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive). It must be on the same element as `routerLink` directive.

Choose one router and remove the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for using ngClass in Angular2+ is `[ngClass]`

Also to avoid the error as shown in comments

> "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined".

Use safe navigation operator (?.)

```
 <li ui-sref-active="active" [ngClass]="{active: $state?.includes('myapp') }">
```

Comment: Thanks its my typo mistake, now its throwing "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". As i am new to angular could you help me to solve this

Comment: I don't know what is `state$` in your code. Either ways you could try with safe navigation operator (`?.`),  if value is binding `asynchronously` or at a later time. For ex: `{active: $state?.includes('myapp') }"`

Comment: Thanks for your help.